# Rename "user" table in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can I rename "user" table in Laravel? I use version 5.5 but I have only found solutions for version 5.2.

Comment: Use Schema::rename($from, $to);

Comment: Are you actually looking to rename the table or do you want to use another table for user authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to create new migration file using:

```
php artisan make:migration rename_users_table
```

This will generate a file in `database/migrations` folde. Open up that file and paste below code in it:

```
<?php

use IlluminateDatabaseMigrationsMigration;

class RenameUsersTable extends Migration {

   /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
   */
   public function up()
   {
        Schema::rename('foo', 'bar');
   }

   /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
   */
   public function down()
   {
       Schema::rename('bar', 'foo');
   }

}
```

Then migrate it using: `php artisan migrate` and done!

Hope this helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to rename a table name, use following setups

```
php artisan make:migration rename_users_table
```

Then, Inside up function in your newly created migration write following line of code

```
Schema::rename($from, $to);
```

Run command

```
php artisan migrate
```

Where **$from** is the current name of your table and **$to** is new name of your table